# How to change a cell value of a column based on cell value of another corresponding columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Pasting the sample rows.

```
Order Number    Serial Number
318696896   Z002
319105547   Z002
319105547   Z001
319161135   Z002
319161135   Z002
319161135   Z001
319161135   Z002
319305928   Z002
319305928   Z001
319750023   Z001
319977802   Z002
319977802   Z001
319977802   Z002
320001459   Z001
320001459   Z002
320001459   Z002
320001459   Z002
320016159   Z001
320028629   Z002
320028629   Z001
```

e.g. 3rd row Order Number `319105547` is `Z001`, here I have to change the 2nd row's Serial Number from `Z002` to `Z001`, like wise I have to do the changes for other Order Number.

Comment: what's the logic behind changing the Serial Number? Do you just select the last one?

Comment: How are the edits stored that you want to make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def correct_serial(df):
    serial_nos = df['Serial Number'].values
    if 'Z001' in serial_nos:
        df.loc[:, 'Serial Number'] = 'Z001'

    return df

df = df.groupby('Order Number').apply(correct_serial)
```

So if an Order Number has a 'Z001' Serial Number, it'll change all the Serial Number for that Order Number to 'Z001', otherwise retain what's being used.

Comment: Zero thank you for the support. The above code is changing or replacing Serial Number column to Z001.

Comment: Order Number have multiple Items, each items may or may not have the serial number, if a single item in the order number have an serial number (Z001) only then rest of the items in the order number should replace Z002 to Z001 other wise the Z002 should remain as it is for that particular order number

Comment: @LawrenceJacob gotcha. will change answer.

Comment: Hi Zero thank you for the Answer it worked, it was my mistake.

Comment: No worries :) Please mark it answered so future viewers can see